# SQL order by date, time

Tags: php, sql

I have (time) column in my database which is of DATETIME type, and I need to store the timezone captured from user while registration.

I use the following to store the date and time.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-3');
$time =  date('D j\, M Y h:i:s a');
```

And I need to get the latest date in database by using

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER_BY date, time WHERE ID='$_SESSION[email]'";
```

Is it correct ?